# Why is namespace not coming in output after dataweave transformation?

Tags: xml, dataweave

I have to do one to one mapping of two schemas. Both schema are same. In the expected output the namespace is there but in the response namespace is not coming in a tag.
Sample XML-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <FndtMsg xmlns="http://dfr.com/BFR/bringr">
   <OrigMsg>
      <Pmnt xmlns:ns1="http://dfr.com/BFR/bringr">
         <ns1:Document xmlns:ns1="http://adar.com/adaR/ada">
            <ns1:RsltnOfInvstgtn>

            </ns1:RsltnOfInvstgtn>
         </ns1:Document>
      </Pmnt>
   </OrigMsg>
```

Response that I am getting-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <FndtMsg xmlns="http://dfr.com/BFR/bringr">
    <OrigMsg>
       <Pmnt>
          <ns1:Document xmlns:ns1="http://adar.com/adaR/ada">
             <ns1:RsltnOfInvstgtn>
             </ns1:RsltnOfInvstgtn>
          </ns1:Document>
       </Pmnt>
    </OrigMsg>
  </FndtMsg>
```

Can I do something so that namespace shows when it is in sample message otherwise not?

Answer (score 1):

DataWeave outputs a namespace the first time it is used only. Any standards based parser should have no problem with that. If for readability you want to output the namespace at an specific element you can emit a dummy attribute that uses it.

Example:

```
Pmnt @(ns1#someattribute: ''): {
...
}
```

Source https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/DataWeave-generate-namespace-declarations-at-the-root-level-of-the-output-XML